# Showing tabular data in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to show data from a web service with a limited amount of rows and with different number of columns (2-5 according to the ws call).

I don't know what kind of view is better to use: is it better to use a ListView with a dynamic layout using LayoutInflater or should i use a TableLayout as if it was a html page?

Answer (score 1):

You can either go with Gridlayout that would be with more ease or go with TableLayout.

Using a TableLayout provide more structured and user specific look then ListView, you can make modification as per your need. like adding separators with rows, images ot arrows on the different TableRows. so best will be either Girdview or TableLayout.